# How to create loop in wordpress based on tag?

Tags: php, wordpress

I included tags to each one of my custom posts on my site. When a user clicks on one of the tags, I want them to go to the page that spits out all custom posts with that specific tag. I have a tag.php page with all the html/css that I need. How can I create this loop?

My site already accomplishes this except with categories so I have been trying to modify the categories code to spit out tag. This is the code that I am using for the categories that I want to modify to spit out for tags -

```
  <?php       
          query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'custom', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
             'tax_query' => array(
             array(
               'taxonomy' => 'custom_categories',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => $term->slug
             )),
            )
           );

           if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
           $imagecustom = wp_get_attachment_image_src(                      
 get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
           $files_url = explode("uploads", $imagecustom[0]);
           $image_url= home_url('/').'wp-content/timthumb.php?
  src=/uploads'.$files_url[1].'&w=200&h=200&zc=1'; 
           $args = array(
            'post_id' => get_the_ID(), // use post_id, not post_ID
           'count' => true //return only the count
           );
            $commentsalltype = get_comments($args); ?>
```

Comment: Please check the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/4002/querying-posts/13973/using-wp-query-object#t=20161023073853172693) and never ever use  `query_posts` to make a custom query.

Comment: Why is query_posts bad to make a custom query? I am not the one who wrote the code but it seems to be working fine on  the site as far as I can tell. I am a novice when it comes to php/wordpess so  forgive me if  my questions are basic. I am still reading up on this stuff.

Comment: If you've read the documentation I've posted above it says: `query_posts()` overrides the main query, and can cause problems in the rest of your theme. Any time you need to modify the main query (or any query for that matter) is to use `pre_get_posts` filter. This will allow you to modify the query before it ran. You should use `WP_Query()`